# Recording object method calls to generate automated test

Tags: .net, testing, .net-3.5, automated-tests

I have an object with large interface and I would like to record all its method calls done during a user session. Ideally this sequence of calls would be available as source code:

```
myobj.MethodA(42);
myobj.MethodB("spam", false);
...
```

I would then convert this code to a test case to have a kind of automated smoke/load test.

[WCF Load Test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) can do this for WCF services and CodedUI test recorder can do this for UIs. What are my options for a POCO class? I am in position to edit application code and replace the object in question with some recording/forwarding proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could conceivably do this with Rhino.Mocks.

```
var code_builder = new StringBuilder();

var myobj = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyObj>();

myobj.Stub(x => x.MethodA(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(x => code_builder.AppendLine(
        string.Format("myobj.MethodA({0});", x.Arguments[0]));

myobj.Stub(x => x.MethodB(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<bool>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(x => code_builder.AppendLine(
        string.Format("myobj.MethodB({0}, {1});", x.Arguments[0], x.Arguments[1]));
```

Once you've recorded all of the values, you've got all the calls in the `StringBuilder`, and you can do with that what you will.

It might actually be less work to create a new implementation of the interface that builds up the code in a similar fashion within each method. You may need the implementation to actually *function* in order for the user to get through the session, in which case you could create a class that derives from or decorates your implementation of the interface, and adds this code-building functionality while forwarding calls to/from the "normal" object.

Comment: Thanks, but this requires coding `string.Format` for each method and the interface is too large to do that by hand.